# SQL Queries tuning into CRM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have question regarding MS Dynamics CRM and SQL.

We have CRM 2015 on-prem., we do get lot of warning messages in windows app log that such and such queries exceeded threshold value. Eventually bunch of this warnings lead to an error of failed workflow/plugin.

We ask MS and they recommended to use SQL Server Tuning Advsior and Profiler to optimize those queries, when we ran SQL Server Tuning Advsior and profiler, we got result that this query can be improved by 54% or 65% via applying following changes. Most of them are indexing.

My question is how to create/modify/apply these recommendations in running/live CRM application?

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating indexes is a expensive operation, because it has to build the index for the existing records.

If you could do it in the evenings, and you can afford having some downtime, go for that option. If you have a SQL Server cluster / high availability solution, it would be best to do it for each node separately to avoid downtime.

Comment: Thanks Jordi, but even after creating indexes how do we let CRM know that it hase to do Insert, Update, Select operation based on indexes? because queries which I am talking about for which we get warnings are like user searching for "Smith" in home page of CRM and this "Smith" can be in Clients, Employees, User etc. we get warning message that this took 203 seconds which exceeded threshold value but when we run that query directly into SQL Server it comes up in like 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: Hi @user2040021, indexes are always used for improving queries, but it will negatively affect inserts and updates, because it has to not only insert the record, but also maintain the index tree.  You won't be able to do that, it is basically SQL Server that decides the best execution plan based on the existing indexes and the query itself.

Comment: You might wanna try to execute a query execution plan or estimated query execution plan, for one of the slow queries, and SQL server will recommend you create any indexes if needed.

Comment: Thanks Jordi, for your reply, but you are right point above your last one that once we create indexes it's gonna take more time to insert or update the records. Now we getting warnings for Query execution time exceeded threshold for SELECT queries after implementing indexes we will start getting warning messages for Select and Insert statement, I guess!!

Comment: No problem. Inserts should be ok unless you have a massive amount of data / transactions. Your best bet is the Query Execution plan which will give you an approximate figure of performance improvement.

Comment: Do you have any kind of document or reference material so that I can pass it to CRM guys since I am the SQL person and I need to let CRM guys know who kind of at this stage that they are saying NO NO to do anything from backend of CRM from SQL end and doesn't know what to do with Warnings and how get rid of them as well. so....you know what I meant.

Comment: if you don't then it's fine too. But you did great help! THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: No worries, could you please mark the answer as valid then? I've updated my profile there now so maybe you could get in touch if you need further details cause maybe this question is getting too long?  :)

Comment: Thank you Jordi. I will contact you if I need more info in how to do this in detail.